# Ошибка при установке MSSQL2014

Tags: sql-server

Недопустимый ключ продукта SQL Server.  Код ошибки 0x858C0017.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачал с сайта: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?PId=1682

Comment: ну а ключ то откуда у вас?

Comment: @teran, Не знаю

Comment: SQL Server  это коммерческий продукт, требующий покупки лицензии и ввода лицензионного ключа при установке. Есть бесплатная версия SQL Server Express с несколько ограниченными функционалом и службами. Также есть Developer версия.